# CSS to position a hyperlink at the bottom of an absolute-positioned div in IE9

Tags: html, css

Here's my markup:

```
<div class="container" style="position:absolute; height:300px;">
    <div class="target" style="height:50px;">here's my target</div>
</div>
```

I need to make `.target` positioned at the bottom of `.container` without changing `.container`'s position.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ns034mhk/

Answer (score 3):

Add `position:absolute;bottom:0;` to `.target`'s style.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid general confusion regarding absolute positioned elements make sure:

- container element has `position :relative;`
- target element has a horizontal and a vertical style ( `left:0; bottom:0;` );
- target element or the stuff you put inside has height and width ( text works just fine even without )